# image overlapping the other divs

Tags: css

I've an issue with CSS in magento - but I think this is a general CSS question:

I have the code below, which is showing an image, with a text box aligned to the top left of it. (which seems to work OK).

However, the image itself is not 'clearing' properly. The actual page or other divs are overlapping the image - so half of it is hidden. Its as though the image is floating in the background.

How can I force it so the whole image is shown and gets the space it needs?

```
<h2>title</h2>
<h3>sub-title</h3>
<h3>some text</h3>
<div style="position: absolute;"><!-- start div for image -->
<img style="z-index: -1; vertical-align:top;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.jpg"}}" alt="" /> <!-- the image --></div>
<!-- end div -->
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1; left: 50%; top: 75%; width: 300px; height: 100px; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background: rgba(24,105,15,0.5); padding: 20px 5px 25px 35px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px;">
    <div style="margin: auto;"><strong>TEXT BOX TITLE</strong>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
    <li>a list of text</li>
    <li>a list of text</li>
    <li>a list of text</li>
    <li>a list of text</li>
    <li>a list of text</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A Jsfiddle wouldbe helpful but my first thought is that it's the absolutely positioned div causing the problem. In any case, its arguable that the image **should** be in the background (as a background-image) as it has elements on top of it.

Comment: thanks... here's a fiddle of the main code. http://jsfiddle.net/bUELH/

Comment: problem is, that is inserted into the "description" box in a magento category, so I can't really show the rest of that

Comment: So how is it **supposed** to look?

Comment: Oh Sorry, well, the image is not getting the space it needs - the shop navigation div and products start over the image. So whatever the command to say "push the page down until the image is done" isn't happening :)

Comment: **[You mean like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/bUELH/2/) **If not,do you have an image of the required look?

Comment: thanks for trying to help Paulie!! Please check this out: http://imgur.com/U9eueUw   ... you can see the kat is overlapped with the shop navigation.

Comment: So it's **supposed** to look like that? Doesn't seem likely. What is the **finished** thing supposed to look like. Does your system inject that inline CSS too..if so, we're in trouble?

Comment: thats how it looks... but the whole image should be visible, THEN the navigation etc.     I guess I'll have to find a new way to align these graphics etc. cheers

Comment: No....it can be done but until we know what the **finished** thing is **supposed** to look like it's pointless offering suggestions that may not be necessary.